# Hardness of Approximation of Set Cover with Growing Size Bound

Tags: reference-request, approximation-hardness, set-cover

I'm considering the **minimum set cover** problem with the constraint that each set contains at most $k$ elements.
Here, $k$ depends on the size of the universe.

For example, $k$ may equal $\log n,\sqrt n$, etc., if the universe is $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

In [this post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/191/bounded-cardinality-bounded-frequency-set-cover-hardness-of-approximation) and [this paper of Luca Trevisan](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=380752.380839), they seem to deal with constant $k$. In [this paper of Uriel Feige](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=285055.285059), there is no size bound.

Though I suspect it is still $(1-o(1))\ln k$ inapproximable, any reference on this would be nice.

Comment: I seem to remember your guess is correct but don’t remember citations off the top of my head...

Comment: This note by Jelani Nelso is not exactly what you are looking for but still be useful. https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il//eccc-reports/2007/TR07-105/revisn01.pdf

Comment: @daniello thanks!

Comment: @ChandraChekuri thanks! Actually I skimmed this before. If I understand correctly, the parameter in it is the number of sets. Then I don’t quite see clear connection here.